# How springConfiguration.xml detects persistence.xml

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm trying to create a Spring and jpa Project.
After googling, I found it's possible by using hibernate with:

```
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="HiSpring"/>
```

However, I want to use only spring and jpa without hibernate.
It's possible ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's the property of [`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPersistenceUnitName-java.lang.String-) which creates `EntityManagerFactory` which is a JPA class (nothing to do with Hibernate). However JPA is just a specification, you need to provide an implementation for it which could be Hibernate or something else.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Could you please help me solving this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647592/spring-jpa-configuration-error

Answer (score 0):

JPA is a specification with different implementations.
You can use Hibernate's JPA implementation or another one if you like.

You can take a look on [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) it helps you easily create repositories with all CRUD operations

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Could you please help me solving this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647592/spring-jpa-configuration-error