# Spring jpa configuration error

Tags: spring, jpa

[Error on Console Picture : Error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pgiS.png)

```html
package com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

 private DataSource dataSource;

 public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
  this.dataSource = dataSource;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void save(Employee employee) 
 {
  String query = "insert into Employee (id, name, role) values (?,?,?)";
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  Object[] args = new Object[] {employee.getId(), employee.getName(), employee.getRole()};
  int out = jdbcTemplate.update(query, args);
  if(out !=0)
  {
   System.out.println("Employee saved with id="+employee.getId());
  }
  else System.out.println("Employee save failed with id="+employee.getId());
 }
}
```

```html
package com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO
{

 private DataSource dataSource;

 public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) 
 {
  this.dataSource = dataSource;
 }

 @Override
 public void save(Employee employee)
 {
  String query = "insert into Employee (id, name, role) values (?,?,?)";
  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  try
  {
   con = dataSource.getConnection();
   ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
   ps.setInt(1, employee.getId());
   ps.setString(2, employee.getName());
   ps.setString(3, employee.getRole());
   int out = ps.executeUpdate();
   if(out !=0)
   {
    System.out.println("Employee saved with id="+employee.getId());
   }
   else System.out.println("Employee save failed with id="+employee.getId());
  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
   try 
   {
    ps.close();
    con.close();
   } 
   catch (SQLException e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
package com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao;

import java.util.List;
import com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeDAO 
{
 public void save(Employee employee);
}
```

```html
package com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.main;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.model.Employee;

public class SpringMain 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
  EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = ctx.getBean("employeeDAOJDBCTemplate", EmployeeDAO.class);
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  emp.setName("Sarsoura Ena");
  emp.setRole("PDG");
  employeeDAO.save(emp);
  ctx.close();
  System.out.println("DONE");
 }
}
```

I created a dynamic web project with both jpa and spring, but I got this Error:
**Could not find or load main class com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.main.SpringMain**
Could you please tell me what I missed.
Bellow are:

**persistence.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence   
                              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">  
  <persistence-unit name="HelloSpring" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
        <class>com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.model.Employee</class>  
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>  
  <properties>  
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />  
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />  
  </properties>  
  </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

**spring.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">  
  <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">  
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
  </bean>  
  
  <bean id="employeeDAOJDBCTemplate" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl">  
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
  </bean>  
  
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
  
  
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdb" />  
  <property name="username" value="root" />  
  <property name="password" value="root" />  
  </bean>  
  
  
  <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"  
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">  
  <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">  
  <list>  
  <value>persistence.xml</value>  
  </list>  
  </property>  
  <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
  </bean>  
  
  
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">  
  <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>  
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="HelloSpring"></property>  
  </bean>  
  
  
  
  
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">  
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>  
  </bean>  
  
  
  
  
</beans>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: more stack errors should be pasted here.

Comment: Hello Demon, I made some changes in my question. Could you please take  a look. Thanks